# For loop is ambiguous

Tags: loops, for-loop

I'm using Visual Basic 2008EE and I have a problem with this loop:

```
If x = CType("new", Primitive) Then
        TextWindow.Write("How many new users would you like to add?     ")
        k = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
        For mt = 1 To k
            NewUserEntry()
        Next
```

and i get this error:

```
"type of 'mt' is ambigious because the loop bounds and the step clause do not convert to the same type"
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure this is VB and not SmallBasic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `ReadNumber` (or more accurately, the type of `k` variable) is probably not an `Integer`. When the compiler wants to infer the type of the `mt`, it fails since `k`, which is specified as the loop bound has one type (probably something like `Double`) and the loop step (implicitly the integer constant 1) has the type `Integer`. The compiler will not automatically assume the type of `mt` since the two don't match.

```
For mt As Integer = 1 To k
     NewUserEntry()
Next
```